# How can I process FCM data only message in react native(iOS)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

On Android, I can get and process 'data only messages' like these codes.

**bgMessaging.js**

```
// @flow
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

**index.js**

```
import bgMessaging from './src/bgMessaging'; // <-- Import the file you created in (2)

// Current main application
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeFirebaseDemo', () => bootstrap);
// New task registration
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging); // <-- Add this line
```

but, on iOS how can I process 'data only messages', when app is killed(not on the process)?

--

I want to display notifications with some logic.

If the server sends below data.

```
{
    "to": "asdf",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "mutable_content": true,
    "data": {
        title: "{name} hellow!"
    }
}
```

App should getting user name's from database(like realm).
and show notifications like **"Tom hellow"**

How can I do that in react-native(ios)?

Answer (score 1):

Please replace `data` into `aps`or you can another parameter aps or you can take data dictionary inside  aps

```
     "to": "asdf",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "mutable_content": true,
    "data": {
        title: "{name} hellow!"
    },
  "aps": {
        title: "{name} hellow!"
    }
```

Comment: @devkingsejong data will be replaced by your backend team in your payload.

Comment: I mean, I want to replace data on a mobile phones.

Comment: to is "Topic" so, I should process that data on mobile phones

Comment: notification is shown only `aps` is provide in the payload by the backend team. Data isn't mandatory as a parameter in payload.

Comment: I knew. if, backend team payload "aps" data, how can I get that data? even app is killed.

Comment: take data parameter separately in payload but `aps` will be required for notification.

Comment: I mean.. I want to get aps data by code... onMessage and RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage can't get messages when app is killed..  sorry for my bad english.

Comment: take `aps` separately and take aps data that you want to display in another parameter lets say `data` and extract the data from this parameter in onMessage.

Comment: but, if app is killed, onMessage func is not working.

Comment: any solution? @devkingsejong